# Avoid execution of Laravel boot() function's events in eloquent model

Tags: php, oop, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a `boot()` function in my model that looks like this,

```
public static function boot() { 

    parent::boot();

    // new item created 
    static::created(function($proof) {
      //Fire an event
    }
}
```

the created function fires everytime I fire something like this, `$proof->save()`

is there a way to by pass firing the created function, there are some scenarios where I do not want to run the functionality within that method?

If it makes any difference I am running Laravel 4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `flushEventListeners()` before you do the create. Example:

```
$data = [];

if ( //SOMETHING ) {
    User::flushEventListeners();
} 

User:create($data);
```

Note that this will prevent all events from firing, not just *created*.

Comment: Assuming it will only do it for that instance? I don't need "unflush" aftewards?

Comment: @Udders yes, this is only for the model that it's being called on and for the current request only.